# Freetype can't find all glyph indexes, even in standard ASCII range

Tags: c++, unicode, ascii, freetype

while learning OpenGL in C++, I've been trying to get textrendering to work. However, I seem to have problems when trying to load certain glyphs when using freetype.

As a first step, I'm trying to load the ASCII + extended ASCII range into 1 big texture. However, I'm seein gaps for certain glyphs. See the image below:
[image]

All I'm doing is just iterating over the ASCII range for now like this:

```
for (int c = 32; c < 256; c++)
{
    int glyph_index = FT_Get_Char_Index(face, c);
    DEBUGINFO("Looked for char index for {}. Got index = {}", (char)c, glyph_index);
    if (FT_Load_Glyph(face, glyph_index , FT_LOAD_RENDER))
    {
        DEBUGERROR("Could not load glyph! {}", letter);
    }
}
```

I've also tried using FT_Load_Char directly but that does not work either. The index is always 0 for some of the ASCII values. I am using the default Arial font used by windows and the glyphs are present in the font. If I manually lookup the index of the blank rectangles and use that as an index for FT_Load_Glyph then they display just fine. So for some reason FT_Get_Char_Index is not able to find these glyphs in the font. Another test I did was to try and find the character by unicode value but the result is the same.
So FT_Get_Char_Index(face, '\u007E') yields me a valid index for the tilde character but FT_Get_Char_Index(face, '\u00C7') which should correspond to "Ç" returns 0 as index, even when it is in the font.

If someone knows what I am doing wrong I'd be very grateful!
Thanks.

Comment: Try `0xC7` instead of `'\u00C7'`, just in case.

Comment: Thank you @HolyBlackCat, that worked. I wonder why some unicode chars work by using '\u' ,notation though.

Comment: @steven: `\u00C7` is a notation for your compiler _source_, which it will translate into its internal form (perhaps UTF-8, i.e. `{0xC3,0x87}`.) Being a character constant `''` allows to compile but it might be transformed into a multibyte constant, probably `0x87C3`. Freetype does not expect such translation to occur, it expects the plain Unicode codepoint, untranslated. You might also try `u'\u00C7'` on a C11 compiler, or perhaps `L'\u00c7'` if wide-chars are using Unicode encoding: this will request the compiler to use Unicode for character encoding.